# Ubuntu 22.04 problem with ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, 22.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on two different computers and they share a confusing behaviour:

- From these 22.04 I can connect to others in the local network, with no issues
- From these 22.04 I can't connect to an external computer, long delay and timed out (see below)
- Also has an Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS in my local network, from that 20.04 I can connect to that same external computer
- From that external computer I can connect to the 22.04 computers

I think this problem:

- is not related with firewalls, I don't have any installed, or router issues
- is not related with RSA issues, I share the same keys in all computers
- is not related with port, I use the default 22 port

Find here the full verbose output, hope it helps:

```
alice:~$ ssh -vvv externalHost
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "externalHost" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup external-host:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to externalHost [XXXXX] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address XXX port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host externalHost port 22: Connection timed out*
```

Using strace I detected the last system calls, when execution is blocked before timed out

```
...
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, [128 => 16]) = 0
getpid()                                = 10276
setsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [16], 4)  = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(22), sin_addr=inet_addr("externalHost-IPaddress")}, 16) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
```

Comment: `ping`, `traceroute` and `nmap` to external host?

Comment: ping and traceroute shows external connection is available, and also nmap (22/tcp  open  ssh). As I commented the two 22.04 and the 20.04 ubuntu machines are in the same local network, with a router to connect to internet. But while 20.04 allows external ssh connection, 22.04 machines does not.

Comment: OS and SSH version of the "externals" ?

Comment: I tested with several Ubuntu and debian versions, in particular: OS:"Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS" and SSH: "OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020"

Comment: Just for info: I had a similar problem, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1427657/ssh-git-commands-stuck-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I can't comment, I'll put it as an answer. I had the same problem, after hours of searching found something that fixed it.

I added

```
 IPQoS none
```

To my /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Looks like something changed in the ssh client in the last version and has troubles communicating with your local router.

I hope it helps.

Comment: You've finished several hours of trying and error, and error, and error. THANK you!

Answer (score 0):

If it still doesn't work, try

```
GSSAPIAuthentication no
```

Answer (score 0):

If not works then you can try by commenting below line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

`KbdInteractiveAuthentication no`

And restart ssh service,
`systemctl restart ssh`