# SSH/GIT commands stuck after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ssh, 22.04, git

After upgrading to **Ubuntu 22.04** from Ubuntu 20.04 I have some problems with `git` commands.
For example a simple `git clone` or `git pull` from github just hang/freeze forever without any error.

After some investigations it looks like the problem is with `ssh`.

This works as expected:

```
$ ssh git@github.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi davideicardi! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

While using `-T` ([as suggested by github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection)) it just hangs forever:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
```

If I use `-Tv` it stops after the following output:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/davide/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:MY_PUB_KEY agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/davide/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:MY_PUB_KEY agent
Authenticated to github.com ([140.82.121.3]:22) using "publickey".
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/davide/.ssh/known_hosts for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /home/davide/.ssh/known_hosts2 for github.com / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /home/davide/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_ADDRESS = "it_IT.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_NAME = "it_IT.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_MONETARY = "it_IT.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_PAPER = "it_IT.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_IDENTIFICATION = "it_IT.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_TELEPHONE = "it_IT.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_MEASUREMENT = "it_IT.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_TIME = "it_IT.UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_NUMERIC = "it_IT.UTF-8"
```

I have tried regenerating the ssh key using `ed25519` but without any change.

If I run `GIT_TRACE=true git pull` I get the following output:

```
11:59:41.975683 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git pull
11:59:41.976410 run-command.c:654       trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok
11:59:41.977594 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git fetch --update-head-ok
11:59:41.978231 run-command.c:654       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_PROTOCOL=version=2 ssh -o SendEnv=GIT_PROTOCOL git@github.com 'git-upload-pack '\''MY_ORG/MY_REPO.git'\'''
```

Router and internet connection is correct, because with another PC it works as usual.

I don't have any specific ssh config, I just use the default one.

I also tried reinstalling git without luck.

Any idea?

### Update 1

Using `IPQoS=throughput` fix the problem, for example using `ssh -T -o IPQoS=throughput git@github.com` or adding `IPQoS throughput` to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. See also [IPQoS options](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/ssh_config.5.html).

But I don't know why... Someone has any explanation?